# How to use Expected condition in selenium with node js

Tags: node.js, selenium

Please suggest how to import Expected Condition class in selenium using node js

Answer (score 0):

To use the expected conditions Service you have to integrate [**wdio-wait-for**](https://webdriver.io/docs/wdio-wait-for/) a [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) library which  supplies a set of common conditions that provides functionalities to wait for certain conditions till a defined task is complete.

Installation:

```
npm i -D wdio-wait-for
```

As an example,

- To wait for an alert to be present:

  ```
  const EC = require('wdio-wait-for');

  browser.waitUntil(EC.alertIsPresent(), { timeout: 5000, timeoutMsg: 'Failed, after waiting for the alert to be present' })
  ```

  or

  ```
  const { alertIsPresent } = require('wdio-wait-for');

  browser.waitUntil(alertIsPresent(), { timeout: 5000, timeoutMsg: 'Failed, after waiting for the alert to be present' })
  ```

  or

  ```
  browser.waitUntil(alertIsPresent(), { timeout: 5000, timeoutMsg: 'Failed, after waiting for the alert to be present' })
  ```

Comment: I am getting  "TypeError: browser.waitUntil is not a
function"   for above solution.

Comment: Check the link for [wdio-wait-for](https://webdriver.io/docs/wdio-wait-for/) if it helps.

Comment: Not Selenium, but looks like an interesting alternative.  In Selenium NodeJS as asked, the package to import is called [until](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html)